# Add parameters in VBA function while passing through Python script

Tags: excel, vba, pywin32, xlwings

I want to pass **`path` variable** into `Btn_Archive_Click` to the VBA macros function.

Below is my Python Code.

```py
def Btn_Archive_Click():
    # open the excel workbook from the specified file
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.join(folderpath,filename))
        
    # insert the macro-string into the excel file
    excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    excelModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)
    path = filepath
    excel.Application.Run(Btn_Archive_Click) # Want to pass path parameter in Btn_Archive_Click function.
```

Below is my VBA code.

```vb
Sub Btn_Archive_Click(filepath As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)
```

After Changing Code to below it works.

```py
def Btn_Archive_Click():
    # open the excel workbook from the specified file
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.join(folderpath,filename))
        
    # insert the macro-string into the excel file
    excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    excelModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(macro)
    path = filepath
    excel.Application.Run("Module6.Btn_Archive_Click",path) # Want to pass path parameter in Btn_Archive_Click function.
```

Comment: I do not work with pythin but try this... `excel.Application.Run("YourFile.xlsm!Module1.Btn_Str_Click", filepath)`. Here `YourFile.xlsm` is the name of the file where the VBA code is. `Module1` is the name of the module where the `Btn_Str_Click` procedure is.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Passing function in quotes giving following error. "Cannot run the macro 'Btn_Archive_Click'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Comment: Indeed, because you don't have `Btn_Archive_Click` in VBA. You have `Btn_Str_Click`.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I have mentioned wrong function in vba, but there is Btn_Archive_Click in my code. I will edit my question.

Comment: [`Application.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.run) expects the macro name in the first argument, as a string, and that macro's arguments in its subsequent arguments. So `excel.Application.Run("Btn_Archive_Click", path)` is correct. If it cannot find the macro after that, then elaborate what kind of macro it is and where it resides in Excel.

Comment: Can you type the exact code that you are trying inside `excel.Application.Run()`?

Comment: @GSerg - Still not working. My Macros are located in Module6 of excel file.

Comment: @SiddharthRout While passing file name it is giving following error. "com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)"

Comment: `.chm`? Are you sure? chm files do not have macro. Can you debug the code and tell me what is the value of `os.path.join(folderpath,filename)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout os.path.join(folderpath,filename) is path of my main excel file which has extension of .xslm

Comment: Ok if you want us to help you then you have to answer the queries that we have. Vague answers will not help us to help you :) So 3 questions for you... **1.** Can you debug the code and tell me what is the value of os.path.join(folderpath,filename) **2.** Can you type the exact code that you are trying inside `excel.Application.Run()` **3.** As @GSerg mentioned, what kind of macro it is and where it resides in Excel?

Comment: @SiddharthRout `chm files do not have macro` - but they do contain the help on the errors. `'xlmain11.chm'` in this case would correspond to the [`HelpFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/helpfile-property) of the `ErrObject`.

Comment: @Primecoder `While passing file name it is giving following error` - good, which means you have successfully called your `Btn_Archive_Click`, which in turn failed to open whatever you passed in `path`.

Comment: @GSerg Yup I am aware of that. I used to create lot of them using `Help & Manual` App. I  just was not sure what OP is passing as `filename` in `os.path.join(folderpath,filename)`...

Comment: Guys It works now, problem was that, as I was adding excelModule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) Module on every run  it was giving error. After specifying Module no. to it , it works .i.e. excel.Application.Run("Module6.Btn_Archive_Click", path).

Answer (score -1):

Here you are:

```
excel.Application.Run('Btn_Archive_Click("pathere"))
```

Comment: it is giving following error. "ERROR: Btn_Archive_Click() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: Sorry, we should put VBA Sub name into the code,not python def name. I will come back to this, its too complicated on phone, I'll have a look later on PC. We will probably need to add excelfilename.xlsm!subnane ... sort of thing

Comment: I have added more details into my code, it may help you.